# Should programmers itemize testing for projects?

Tags: testing, bug, acceptance-testing

I recently hired a programming team to do a port of my iPad app to the iPhone and Android platforms.

Now, in a separate contract, I am asking them to implement a bunch of tips on how to play the app, similar like you would find in Candy Crush or Cut the Rope.  They want to charge 12 hours @ $35/hr for the "Testing all of the Tips", telling me that normally it would take them more than 25 hours but that they will 'bear the difference'.

I am not familiar with this level of itemization, but maybe it's a new practice?  I am used to devs doing their own quality control, and then having a testing/acceptance period.

They are using Cocos 2D-X, and they say that the tips going to multiple platforms makes all of the hours jack up.  I feel like they might be overcharging, and it's difficult for me to know because it's kind of like with a mechanic.  "It took us 5 hours to replace the radiator".  How can you dispute that?

It seems to me that most of you would charge for the work but NOT for hours that you are 'testing'. Am I missing something?

Thanks for any help and advice you can give!

Comment: "They want to charge 12 hours @ $35/hr for the 'Testing all of the Tips' [BUT] I am used to devs doing their own quality control" Sounds like the exact same thing, except itemized a bit differently.

Comment: They gave you an itemized invoice, basically they're giving you the *option* that they don't test it. Up to you whether you want your stuff tested. Perhaps the part is so simple they don't feel it likely they could mess it up, and are therefore giving you the option that they don't test that part. Your call whether you want them to test it or not. The "doing their own quality control" bit is something that they do but it doesn't take 0 hours, it takes time and you either pay for that time or you don't and you don't get that time.

Comment: Contract disputes and invoicing practices are not on topic for this site.

Comment: When you get work for $35/hr, they're only going to do *exactly* the work that you agreed to do.  If you didn't specify hours for QA, you get code that the dev writes and says "yup, it works for me".  Consider yourself lucky that QA hours are cheaper than dev hours.

Comment: I find it odd that this could be considered off-topic.  Maybe I wasn't clear, so I apologize. This is NOT a contract dispute.  I contracted them to do a port for a certain amount, and now I would like to add some simple tips in a different contract. Their proposal came back with "testing hours" built in.   My question is about the general concept of "is it an industry practice to charge to test to see if code is working properly" if you charge hourly.  How is that off-topic? Many could benefit from hearing the wisdom from honest and skilled devs in here who know.

Comment: Retitled, reworded (and submitted for reopen) to be more appropriate and about itemization of testing rather than about contracts with programmers which is kinda how it looked.

Comment: What am I missing with this question? Software Developers (at least semi-competent ones) don't just code and throw things out the door without doing some form of testing to make sure the sw works. Whether they lump that testing in coding or separate it out; it is all the same. They don't go on the clock while coding but off the clock when testing.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant -- thanks for the edits! This is my first time using this forum, sorry for the newbie mistakes everyone...  I am genuinely trying to learn best practices so that I can create win-win scenarios  with the programmers I hire.

Comment: (Dunk). Sure, though what seems blindingly obvious now ('good programmers write tests') was actually not the standard, or even common 20 years ago.  Things have changed a lot and I don't know the OP's background, experience, etc.

Comment: @Dunk -- "Software Developers (at least semi-competent ones) don't just code and throw things out the door without doing some form of testing to make sure the sw works. Whether they lump that testing in coding or separate it out; it is all the same."  -- Yes, of course -- my app is a complicated interactive story app in the App Store and I've been through this before. But I have never ported to multiple platforms before this, and never had anyone propose that they need me to pay 1.5 days of work to play with the app to make sure the code they just wrote is working on different platforms.

Comment: @Patton:Not knowing how complicated your app is, I couldn't say if 1.5 days is long or not. However, for some types of projects 1.5 years of testing (or more) is not unusual.

Answer (score 5):

To determine whether or not the software "works" you and the software developers evaluate the software against the software requirements that you provided to them, and determine whether or not the software they provide to you actually meets those requirements.  The way you direct this process is by *providing testing requirements within the requirements themselves.*

Software requirements should be [specific, measurable, attainable, relevant, and time-bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMART_criteria).  Every requirement *must also be accompanied by clear, specific and unambiguous criteria that demonstrates that the requirement has been met.*  Generally speaking, that means you're defining a test as part of the requirement; if it passes the test, you declare success.  If you have requirements like that, then you already have a built-in mechanism for insuring that your software developers deliver the product that they promised, because they have to demonstrate to you that the software meets each of the requirements, in the manner stated in the requirement.

> #### Tips for writing testable requirements include:
>
> - Use short, direct, complete sentences
> - Make requirements internally & externally consistent
> - Remove ambiguity
> - Make requirements measurable
> - Make requirements finite
> - Include testers in the requirements peer reviews
> - Define a testing strategy for each requirements as  soon as it is specified
> - Trace requirements to test cases

If the tips were part of the original requirements/specifications that you provided to them, and they bid the job on a fixed-cost basis based on those requirements, then they are obligated to deliver to you an app that works.  If they need to test it to make sure that it works when they deliver it, then that's what they need to do.  Otherwise, they will be fixing problems that you find later, for free.

**Further Reading**
[Writing Testable Requirements](http://www.cqaa.org/Resources/Documents/Presentations%202010/Writing%20Testable%20Requirements.pdf)

Comment: Worth noting: 12 hours at $35 per hour sounds like cheap insurance to me.  Just make sure everyone is crystal clear about what that money is paying for.

Comment: I've never seen their testing. I don't know how one can predict precisely what, if anything, it insures.

Comment: @dcaswell: What role do you play in this conversation?

Comment: My role is Commenter. Rather than discussing roles, I was curious whether you would share the criteria you used to judge the testing as cheap.

Comment: @dcaswell: See http://www.quora.com/How-much-does-it-cost-to-build-an-iPhone-app.  Assuming that the testing has added value, it is a tiny cost relative to the total cost of building an app.

Comment: "Worth noting: 12 hours at $35 per hour sounds like cheap insurance to me. Just make sure everyone is crystal clear about what that money is paying for." -- if it were to test the app, sure I agree.  But these tips are a TINY part of the whole project -- $420 is not a lot, but if this is a practice they do on every little improvement, it would tank my budget!

Comment: @Patton77: Then you need to be asking them some pointed questions about cost.  How much is this going to cost me?  How long is it going to take?  Can there be a fixed upper limit on the cost?

Comment: @Patton77: To put it another way, it's not reasonable for them to continuously come up with adhoc charges.  Find a way to pin them on how much it's *actually* going to cost.

Comment: @RobertHarvey -- thank you so much for your insights. Here is some more info... They quoted 71 hours for the implementation of the tips, and an additional 12 hours to 'test' them. So they have given a fixed cost, my issue is the additional 12 hours when 71 hours seems high to begin with.  Because this is my first port, I don't know if going to iPad, iPhone, and Android really would triple hours and 'testing', and if this is reasonable... Would you quote like this?

Comment: @Patton77: I just find it odd that they would break out the testing like that, that's all.  Unless you've specifically stated that you want additional testing, it's more or less understood that programmers deliver code that works, so I don't see the point of a separate line item for testing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey -- I agree with you 100%, thanks for being a sounding board here - much appreciated!